# Error: Adapter Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql is not supported, HOWEVER

Tags: mysql, pdo, phalcon

Edit:

Phalcon version 4.2.0 and php 7.4.3 versions are the compatible versions I was told to used and Im sure that I had scaffolded the users table. But now when I am trying to rescaffold since I added new columns to that table, its telling me   Error: Adapter Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql is not supported
I've checked php -m in command prompt and it says the mysql pdo exists. I dunno what else to do.

Config.php - Here is the file that has the database configuration. Since I already had users scaffolded, I could have checked if users exist and it returned true or false. So I knew this was working before.
<?php

```
use Phalcon\Config;
use Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql as DbAdapter;

    $config = new Config([
        'database' => [
        'adapter'  => DbAdapter::class,
        'host'     => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'dbname'   => 'medical',
    ],
    'application' => [
        'controllersDir' => __DIR__ . '/../app/controllers/',
        'modelsDir'      => __DIR__ . '/../app/models/',
        'viewsDir'       => __DIR__ . '/../app/views/',
        'baseUri'        => '/',
    ],
    ]);

    return $config;
```

services.php - this is where the config for the database information was set from the config.php file

```
   //set the database
    $db = $container->get('config');
    $databaseConfig = $config->database;
    $host = $databaseConfig->host;
    $username = $databaseConfig->username;
    $password = $databaseConfig->password;
    $dbname = $databaseConfig->dbname;
```

also, php.ini has the following:

```
extension=bz2
extension=curl
;extension=dba
extension=com_dotnet
;extension=enchant
;extension=ffi
extension=fileinfo
;extension=ftp
extension=gd2
extension=gettext
extension=gmp
extension=intl
extension=imap
extension=ldap
extension=mbstring
extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=mysqli
;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=odbc
extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pdo_sqlite
```

Comment: Edit question to include versions of products along with the full error output. What code is throwing the error message?

Comment: Please share your code for the database service and for your model. `config` could be useful too.

Comment: I made the edits, let me know if you need more details that I may have missed to share.

Comment: services.php has not `db` service. I will add one in the answers and we can continue there.

Comment: It can read the database, that's not the issue. Its when I am in command prompt and I tell it to 'phalcon scaffold users', thats when it throws the error  Error: Adapter Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql

Comment: Then your issue is with Phalcon Devtools. I don't use them myself, I always create models manually, so I can't help you further with it. What I have read from other users is that you must select the right version of Devtools for Phalcon.

Comment: Its just crazy that it worked once in the past, with all my setup. And now its failing. Thanks Arthur!

Comment: If I remember well, you are working with Ubuntu. If you did an `apt update` check that your default PHP CLI version is 7.4 and not 8.2. All PHP updates set the latest PHP version as default for CLI.

Comment: Ps @CarolineCraig, please tag me if you reply.

Comment: @Arthur, sorry I didnt notice that when you reply, I don't get an email.  I am working in wamp64.

Comment: @CarolineCraig I thought that you had solved the problem. Can you confirm that your CLI version still is 7.4?

Comment: @Arthur, Yes it is still 7.4.33. Ive just checked: OS: Windows NT CAROLINE 10.0 build 22621 (Windows 10) AMD64
  PHP Version: 7.4.33
  PHP SAPI: cli
  PHP Bin: C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.4.33\php.exe
  PHP Extension Dir: C:\php\ext
  PHP Bin Dir: C:\php
  Loaded PHP config: C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.4.33\php.ini
Versions:
  Phalcon DevTools Version: 4.2.0
  Phalcon Version: 4.1.2
  AdminLTE Version: 3.0.1

Comment: @CarolineCraig if you type `phalcon commands help` do you see all the options menu?

Comment: I do! Available commands:
  info             (alias of: i)
  commands         (alias of: list, enumerate)
  controller       (alias of: create-controller)
  module           (alias of: create-module)
  model            (alias of: create-model)
  all-models       (alias of: create-all-models)
  project          (alias of: create-project)
  scaffold         (alias of: create-scaffold)
  migration        (alias of: create-migration)
  webtools         (alias of: create-webtools)
  serve            (alias of: server)
  console          (alias of: shell, psysh)

Comment: @Arthur, forgot to tag you. Yes I do. See above.

Comment: Hi @CarolineCraig, I recently read by chance that pdo_mysql has to be loaded before Phalcon. Check that this is the case in php.ini for CLI (type `php -i` in the command line and find the php.ini file that is being loaded). There you must make sure that Phalcon is being loaded *after* pdo_mysql.

Comment: @Arthur I checked and its in order,  the weirdest thing though is that my psr and phalcon libraries needs the .dll extension but yet I see other extensions doesnt include dll.

Comment: @CarolineCraig no idea then. In the meantime while you find the solution, you can try to create your models manually. It is pretty simple actually.

Comment: @Arthur, thanks for taking the time out. Yes, that is my game plan to move the project forward.

Comment: @CarolineCraig good luck with it. If you don't really need getters and setters, it's quite fast.

Comment: Hi Arthur, I finally revisited this issue and you will not believe it, all I had to do is remove use Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql from the services.php and my scaffold started working again!

Answer (score 0):

`services.php` is not registering the db service. It should look like:

```
$config = $container->get('config');

$container->setShared('db',
     function () use ($config) {
        return new DbAdapter(
            [
                'host' => $config->host,
                'username' => $config->username,
                'password' => $config->password,
                'dbname' => $config->dbname
            ]
         );
     }
);
```

To check that it is working, run a simple query:

```
echo $container->get('db')->fetchColumn('SELECT count(*) FROM `table`');
```

With this first step we can check that the connection to your db is working and the container has a db service. If the check is successful, please share the declaration of your model and your loader. Also, keep into account that your `config.php` file should be registered in the container as well; according to your example:

```
 use Phalcon\Config;

 $config = require_once 'config.php';

 $container->set('config',$config);
```